# How to send Multiple ID's in restful api endpoint

Tags: typescript, angular5, restful-authentication

End point format is   http://localhost:8080/api/user/name/id/uid

and

```
this.http.get('/api/user/' + this.authService.name + this.authService.sid+ this.authService.userid  )
      .subscribe(result => {
        console.log('get ====>' + JSON.stringify(result));
      });
```

Comment: Have you tried to output the `'/api/user/' + this.authService.name + this.authService.sid+ this.authService.userid`? Why not?

Answer (score 0):

just place the **+ '/' +** it will gives the end point format

```
this.http.get('/api/user/' + this.authService.namespace + '/' + this.authService.userid + '/' + this.authService.sid )
```